# How OWASP-ESAPI jar file read properties file in our system using java

Tags: java, properties, owasp

i would like to know what will happen behind the scenes when OWASP-ESAPI jar reads ESAPI.Properties files and Validator.properties in our system using java

Comment: Welcome to SO. please provide the code you have produced so far.

Comment: ValidationErrorList errors = new ValidationErrorList();
  String cookieName = ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("cookie name", name, "HTTPCookieName", 50, false, errors);
String cookieValue = ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("cookie value", value, "HTTPCookieValue", 5000, false, errors);

Comment: the above is the code

Comment: you should add it to the question. And consider sufficient formatting.